# Bootstrap multiselect plugin not working dropdownlist not showing

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 with the multiselect plugin. I have the multiselect dropdown in a modal

multiselect is initiallized like:

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    maxHeight: 150,
    buttonWidth: 250, 
});
```

The first time round when the modal is first loaded it works fine - I can select the options from the dropdownlist. But when I close the modal (pressing the search submit button) I deselect all the options in the dropdown like this:

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect('deselect', $('.multiselect').val());
```

The problem is when I open the modal the second time the button is visible but no dropdownlist, i have tried to replace above with multiselect.refresh & multiselect.rebuild. It seems a css issue or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the exemple http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/
you could deselect options using :

```
$('option').each(function(element) {
    $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
});
```

I Hope it may help you.

Comment: Tony I did try the above but again same problem the options are deselected cause it shows "non selected" but when clicked on only gives a thin grey line below the button and thats all.

Comment: You may have to refresh the multiselect after deselect using : $('.multiselect').multiselect('refresh');

Comment: Tony I tried that also nothing seems to work after I am deselecting the the items, have tried refresh, rebuild, deslect. am using bootstrap 2.3.2 I also got multiselect file 2.3.2. still not working

Comment: maybe your options are empty. Do you fill option with an ajax call or somthing else ? or did you try with the code you wrote upper ?